# ValueError : Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer`

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to  build a classifier for mixed data consisting of text and categorical data. I want to process text data using an embedding layer followed by a lstm cell and a dense network.
For Categorical data, I created a dense Network.
I want to concatenate output of two netowrks and pass through another dense network.

Here is my code

```py
def create_model():
    seq  = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
    embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length)(seq)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128))(embeddings)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(x)

    categorical_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape =(4198, ) )
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(categorical_input)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(y)

    combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, y])
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(combined)
    z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(z)
    outs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs = [seq, categorical_input], outputs = outs)

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

And Here is the full Traceback

[image: The image contains screenshot of traceback]

```
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1585487845.py in create_model()
     14     z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(z)
     15     outs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')
---> 16     return tf.keras.Model(inputs = [seq, categorical_input], outputs = outs)


     17 ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f30ecaee790>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error message with trace?

Comment: Also, try using `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()[x, y]` instead of `tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, y])`. With the Functional API, you have to use layers, not tensors.

Comment: It doesn't work. Generates another TypeError

Comment: @Djinn `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()[x, y]` is not a correct syntax. The problem here is: `outs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')`, it should have been `outs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')(z)`

Comment: Ahh you're right I missed that dense layer. With Concatenate, the list should be in their own parentheses.